# cygwin startxwin.bat does not work

Tags: cygwin, x11

I tried to install x11 for cygwin. The installation appears to go well BUT there is no startxwin.bat file as described in the docs. I downloaded this file manually and put it in the right place. It runs and in taskmanager I see xwin.exe - BUT there is no "TERMINAL".

Can anyone help?

PS: I am trying to get x11 because I believe I need it to plot prettily in gnuplot - could some confirm that I do need x11 for that.

OUTPUT from calling startxwin in CYGWIN-terminal:

```
$ startxwin

Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.13.3.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 LskyHome2 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39 i686
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (WoW64)
Package: version 1.13.3-1 built 2013-03-09

XWin was started with the following command line:

X :0 -multiwindow

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension GLX
(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/moon sky/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw installed, allowing ShadowDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - Windows NT, allowing PrimaryDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 0000001f
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1920 height: 1080 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
winInitMultiWindowWM - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
GL_VERSION:     3.3.0
GL_VENDOR:      NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER:    GeForce GTX 260/PCI/SSE2
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample and GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) 450 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) AIGLX: Set GLX version to 1.4
(II) 333 fbConfigs
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/OTF/, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 960 540
(--) 5 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winBlockHandler - pthread_mutex_unlock()
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winClipboardProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winInitMultiWindowWM - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.

moon sky@LskyHome2 ~
$ Warning: Cannot convert string "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Unable to load any usable ISO8859 font
Warning: Unable to load any usable ISO8859 font
Error: Aborting: no font found
```

Answer (score 1):

`startxwin.bat` has been removed in favor of `startxwin.exe`... http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin.xfree/20615

Look for it in `/bin`

Comment: I ran "startx" in the cygwin terminal and got this:(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/moon/.XWinrc not found

Comment: @jturney. I get very similar result. I have added output from command to question above

Comment: In 2021, I cannot see `starxwin.exe` in Cygwin64 anymore, all I can see is a file `startxwin` which is actually an `sh` script (it does work fine, from what I've tried)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need X11 for gnuplot on Windows.  See:  http://www.gnuplot.info/ :

```
Gnuplot supports many different types of output
          interactive screen display:           cross-platform (Qt, wxWidgets, x11) or system-specific (MS Windows, OS/2)
          static screen display:                system-specific (OSX(aqua), svga, ...)
          direct output to file:                postscript (including eps), pdf, png, gif, jpeg, LaTeX, metafont, emf, svg, ...
          mouseable web display formats:        HTML5, svg
```

However, it might be easier to use a different precompiled binary.  See:  http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~pjohnson/Gnuplot/windows_gnuplot.html

Comment: Thank you BUT I work within a cygwin terminal, and need to call GNUPLOT with command line arguments when I want to plot something. I think calling GNUPLOT separately will be cumbersome

Comment: I tried your suggestion - and I DO find it useful. However, it seems to have some peculiarities. LIKE smooth has no cumulative option - do you know a way around?